# Conditional Distributions and Rationals

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

If $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$, what is the conditional distribution of $U$ given that $U$ is rational? Intuitively, it would be uniform, but we cannot have a uniform distribution over a countable set.

Comment: "$U$ is rational" is a measure zero event, so the sigma algebra generated by $U$ has only events of measure zero or one. Therefore, the conditional expectation is just the constant random variable given by the expectation of $U$, which is half. (If you are speaking of conditional expectation over a sigma algebra as a random variable).

Answer (score 1):

The rationals form a null set, i.e. a set of probability $0$, and conditional probabilities given a null set are not defined.

Comment: Why are there cases where we do such conditioning? For example, say $(X_n)$ is a Poisson process - then, for a fixed $n$, we can talk about the joint conditional distribution of $X_1, \dots, X_n$ given $X_{n+1} = x$, even if the event that $X_{n+1} = x$ has measure zero.

Comment: @KurtlandChua : What do you mean by "$(X_n)$ is a Poisson process"? Poisson processes $N(t)$ take integer values and $P[N(t)=k]>0$ for all $k$. You might want another example like "what if $X$ is uniform over $[0,1]$" for which things like $E[Y|X=x]$ or $E[Y|\sigma(X)]$ make sense. (I would be interested if Robert has any insight/discussion of the distinctions.)

Comment: @Michael Oh, I guess going off of your definition, what I had in mind was $X_n = \sup_{t > 0, N(t) < n} t$ (i.e. when the arrivals happen)

Comment: There is an exception for conditioning with respect to the value of a continuous random variable.  So you can talk about conditional probabilities given $U = u$ for $u \in [0,1]$.  But not conditional probabilities given $U \in\ $ some set.